# Programs detecting pipe on its output to disable coloration

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Some programs have a colored output (such as `grep` or `emerge` on my gentoo system), but if their output is piped, into `less` for example or into a file, the colored output is disabled.

Yet, I know `less` is able to display colored output, as commands such as

```
ccze -A < /var/log/emerge.log | less
```

do display colored text. So I have two questions here :

- Is it possible to "trick" other colored output programs to keep the coloration ?
  I would like to keep colors if I do for example :

  ```
  emerge -puND world | less
  ```
- How do these programs detect that their output is redirected ?

Comment: From the emerge man page: --color < y | n > Enable or disable color output. This option will override NOCOLOR (see make.conf(5)) and may also be used to force color output when stdout is not a tty (by default, color is disabled unless stdout is a tty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From stackoverflow - on detecting tty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641414):

> Most commands that do print out those color codes explicitly check if stdout/stderr is a tty (using the isatty command).

[From stackoverflow - on capturing colorized output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515296):

> One way to capture colorized output is with the `script` command. Running `script` will start a bash session where all of the raw output is captured to a file (named typescript by default).

See `man script` for more information.

Comment: script seems like the right answer for the OP. Note also that Bash has the `tty` command and `test -t FD` to determine if FD is a tty. The latter helped me to auto-disable color in a script (the opposite of what the OP wanted but that's how I landed here).
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515778/how-does-a-program-know-if-stdout-is-connected-to-a-terminal-or-a-pipe